# Liferay, cannot load sass mixins from another css file

Tags: sass, liferay, mixins

I'm playing with sass on liferay 6.2. In my css folder, I have a main.css file in which I include all the other css files.

I started creating some mixins to handle some basic css functionnalities. Those mixins work great, as far as I put them in the css file they are used in.

When I'm trying to put it un a mixins dedicated stylesheet, and import this one like the others, it doesn't work. I mean, the stylesheet is properly imported, but the mixins are unusuable from other css files.
This is a strange behaviour, because any other css properties from my mixins.css file work properly.

Thanks for helping

Comment: Are you working directly on the server or are you building a theme (or portlet) and deploy this to the server?

Comment: I'm working both on theme and portlet and I don't need to deploy. It's taken on the fly.

Comment: Try to work in the SDK and deploy (it's quick). Recompiling the SASS stuff is a beast and works best if done compile-time. If that works, you a) have a working environment and b) have a clue on where the issue might be. Liferay IDE (eclipse-based) automatically deploys themes and portlets on save, this might be a good option

Comment: So actually, I understood why this was behaving like this : We are working with a configuration which compile and deploy frontend stuff on the fly. I guess that instead of minifiying all the stuff when saving, liferay keeps files separeted. So this is a common sass issue depending on the environement. But I dont have this in symfony for example but I'm using assetic. So...